# What kind of image file format does the Google Charts QR code generator use?

Tags: html, image, data-uri

If you use the google charts [qr code generator](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes?hl=en) you get html output that looks like this

```
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chartcht=qr&amp;chs=500x500&amp;=Hello+world&amp;choe=UTF-8">`
```

To me that does not look look like a data URI and it has no filename extension either.

What kind of image format is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNG. It doesn't have the `.png` file extension, but it does have the `image/png` MIME type:

> [image]

When loading the image, the browser receives the following header:

```
content-type:image/png
```

This is what lets the browser know that it's a PNG.

Comment: Ah ha! Somehow I missed that.